# WrappedAttributeError 'IsAdminUser' object has no attribute 'authenticate'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm using Django Rest Framework with `permission_classes` to create an API. My understanding is that once I go to that API with an unauthenticated user I should be redirected to the login form, right? Instead, I get the following error:

`WrappedAttributeError at /sessions/api/listPatients/
'IsAdminUser' object has no attribute 'authenticate'`

There's no redirect to the login form... and I don't understand why.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? How to fix that?

Here's the `urls.py`:

```
path('api/getSessions/',
     views.GetSessions.as_view(),
     name="GetSessionsAPI"),
```

And here's the view that I'm trying to go to:

```
class GetSessions(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Session.objects.filter(
                patient__created_by_user=self.request.user)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

and here's the other one raising the error:

```
class ListPatients(generics.ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = PatientsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                return Patient.objects.filter(
                    created_by_user=self.request.user).\
                   filter(curently_active=True)
            except Patient.DoesNotExist:
                raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
WrappedAttributeError at /sessions/api/listPatients/
'IsAdminUser' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/sessions/api/listPatients/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: WrappedAttributeError
Exception Value:    
'IsAdminUser' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
Exception Location: /Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate, line 375
Python Executable:  /Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/patient',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/services',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/notes',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/practice',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/activity_logger',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/session',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/my_calendar',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/session/tests',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/users',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0',
 '/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0/zapiszsesje_2_0']
Server time:    Sat, 17 Nov 2018 15:29:56 +0100
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in wrap_attributeerrors
        yield ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) ...
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('IsAdminUser' object has no attribute 'authenticate'), another exception occurred:
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in inner
                return func(*args, **kwds) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in initial
        self.perform_authentication(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in perform_authentication
        request.user ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__
                self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in wrap_attributeerrors
        six.reraise(type(exc), exc, info[2]) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py in reraise
            raise value.with_traceback(tb) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in wrap_attributeerrors
        yield ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/karol/Development/ZS_2_0/ZS_2_0_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) ...
▶ Local vars
```

UPDATE: 
This error goes away when I change the following line in my base.py settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser', # <- commenting out solves the problem!
    ),
```

However, the line has been added following the book [Two Scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11) ...

Comment: Looks like error occures in another view: `/sessions/api/listPatients/`. Can you show it also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - yes - that must be it, but I don't see what ... Added like you suggested. Any hints?

Comment: Can you add full traceback?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner - added.

Comment: You shouldn't need to have permission validation in a view this need to be a permission class https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions

Comment: Second you should verify that your Authorization grant type is resource and password based as the request.user is None if your using client credentials.

Comment: You're certainly misreading the book. Authentication is not the same as permissions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - yes - I did misread the book!! Thanks - you found it! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out it was my mistake which got uncovered thanks to the comments under my question:

By mistake I have added `'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',` to `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` instead of `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` inside my settings file.

That solved the problem - thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

For me the same problem occurred when by accident I typed in authentication_classes instead of permission_classes

```py
class MyView(ApiView)
  authentication_classes = (AllowAny, ) # Should be permission_classes!  

  def get(request):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create a authentication model, you need TokenAuthentication in your viewsets classes.
for example:

```
class LessonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LessonSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
    premission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```